# Understanding CGPoints in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritekit

I am planning to place three cards on a view which I add to the background. However I wanted to combine two of the cards and replace the first card position with the new card position. Is there any way I can do this?

I am trying to read the selected node position by:

```
CGPoint position = CGPointMake([self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation].position.x, [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation].position.y);
```

However what I read is (0,0).

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

In your scene controller, you should do this inside `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

`touchPos` will have the position inside your scene, and you can do:

```
if ([self.cardOne containsPoint:touchPos]){
    //Do something 
    CGPoint cardOnePosition = self.cardOne.frame.origin;
}
```

If you want to get what node are you touching in a better way, you can subclass SKSpriteNode (for your cards) and from there implement `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, make sure inside init you make `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]`. Then you could set up a delegate from this subclass that calls a method in your scene, and from your scene controll what to do better.